# Declarative macro merge trait and struct bodies

Tags: rust

I would like to call a macro something like this:

```
my_macro! {
  some_ident {
    fn any_number() -> char { 'a' }
    fn of_them() -> char { 'a' }
  }
  other1 {}
  other2 {}
}
```

I would like it to merge all the functions inside the inner block with one or more functions that the macro produces. Something like this:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
  { $a:ident $b:tt $($c:ident $d:tt)+ } => {
    pub struct $a {}
    impl $a {
      fn something_new() { }
      $b
    }
  }
}
```

The above doesn't work, `non-item in item list` compile error, because in that location, it's expecting a list of function definitions, but `$b` is a single block starting with `{`. Using `$b:block` instead gives the same error.

Is there some way to strip the block or something and get the list inside so I can do it this way?

I could try something like this:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
  { $a:ident { $($b:tt)* } $($c:ident $($d:tt)*)+ } => {
    pub struct $a {}
    impl $a {
      fn something_new() { }
      $($b)*
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives a `multiple parsing options` error (apparently the * is greedy). It can't decide to extract another `tt` or match the `}` and move on the `$c:ident`.

I'm guessing I could do some type of `$($v:vis fn $i:ident(...) $b:block)*` spell out the whole match for all the functions but is that really necessary?

Comment: You need to put the functions in an impl block and not inside the struct declaration, but other than that [the second approach works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8838f91aa70f0a019274a96587ed0d52).

Comment: It is also false that it can't decide between matching the `}` for the literal or the `tt`, because unlike other tokens (which will cause this confusion), `}` is a closing bracket, and closing brackets (`)]}`) (as well as opening brackets, `([{`) cannot be matched against alone.

Comment: I simplified my actual code for the question, rather incorrectly. I have corrected it above (but left my mistakes in the text that you pointed out). You're completely right on both accounts, and your comment that the second approach worked helped me find the correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman) pointed out, I made some significant mistakes in the code in the question because of oversimplifying my actual code. I have updated it.

I was misunderstanding the error in the second approach. It ends up it was in the second half of the match around `$d`. It was missing `{...}` around it.

And for the first approach, the answer was in the error message. When I saw `non-item in item list`, I just thought it meant that I was putting something that wasn't a list in there and it was expecting a list. But it meant `item`, as in the item syntax fragment.

The following works. It also works using `tt` instead of `item`, but I think item is more accurate.

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
  { $a:ident { $($b:item)* } $($c:ident { $($d:item)* })+ } => {
    pub struct $a {}
    impl $a {
      fn something_new() { }
      $($b)*
    }
  }
}

my_macro! {
  some_ident {
    fn any_number() -> char { 'a' }
    fn of_them() -> char { 'a' }
  }
  other1 {
    fn any_number();
  }
  other2 {}
}
```